# IIS host name binding gives a 404 error, works when empty

Tags: iis, asp.net-core, hosts, iis-10

I have a somewhat weird problem on my IIS server, running a ASP.NET Core application.

The server runs correctly when there is a binding with an empty host name (wildcard). The localhost and domain name can access it correctly using this method. When putting a localhost binding only, it works on localhost, **however**, when putting my host name (www.mywebsite.com, mywebsite.com), accessing the website using the domain name results in an error 404.

I tried to configure my `hosts` file as far as I can:

```
127.0.0.1 localhost
::1 localhost
127.0.0.1 mywebsite.com
127.0.0.1 www.mywebsite.com
::1 mywebsite.com
::1 www.mywebsite.com
```

(obviously replace mywebsite.com by the real domain name)

Thanks!

Comment: So your trying to access `www.mywebsite.com` on the same server it's hosted on? Can you ping it on the server?

Comment: oh well, i misunderstood the hosts file. I heard that you *should* use the hosts file for something, how do you use it?

Comment: No i think your on the right track. You have to use it. Just wanted to confirm what you are doing. Can you open command prompt and ping `www.mywebsite.com`? What ip do you see?

Comment: After pausing cloudflare, the public IP of the server.

Comment: That’s desired. You explicitly asked IIS to only handle incoming requests whose host header matches ˋlocalhost`. If you want to handle other requests, use blank host name in your site binding, or add other bindings for those host headers.

Comment: That's the point. I set three bindings, one for localhost, one for `mywebsite.com` and another for `www.mywebsite.com`. Accessing the site by using localhost works, but the domains (`(www.)mywebsite.com`) redirect to a 404 not found.

Comment: I test it with no problem from this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/iis/?view=aspnetcore-2.2#create-the-iis-site).Are you sure your machine IP correspond to IP address in host file?

Comment: Apparently the server i'm using is going through a reverse proxy powered by nginx. Is there a way to debug it or something?